# Laravel global way to transfer urls to subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Initially I had all my Routes to my main Domain.

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    'blog'  => 'Front\BlogController',
]);
```

There are lots more controllers.

I could use the route method

```
route('Front\BlogController@getIndex')
```

But now when I am converting those to Subdomain as **subdomain.example.com**

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'), 'middleware' => 'subdomain'], function(){
    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
        'blog'  => 'Front\BlogController',
    ]);
});
```

I will have to go to all the function and add the **$subdomain** parameter to access that variable like this:

```
route('Front\BlogController@getIndex',$subdomain)
```

and I think that will take a long time.

SO is there ant way by which we can assign the subdomain variable to all the functions globally or automatically.

Need Help !!!

Comment: Have you tried just seeing what the value of $subdomain is in the BlogController, like `function getIndex($subdomain) { dd($subdomain); }`, without the `route('Front\BlogController@getIndex',$subdomain)` part?